# Harvesting GeoServer Layer Group ("named tree" mode) with GeoNetwork

Tags: geoserver, wms, geonetwork

I set up harvesting process inside GeoNetwork to harvest my entire GeoServer`s WMS GetCapabilities but it is only returns metadata entries for GS layers, but not for layer groups.

I believe it is somehow related to the fact that Layer Groups contains nested layers and GN only harvest nested children not the entity containing them.

Is it somehow possible to automatically harvest layer groups in mode "named tree" from GeoServer to GeoNetwork metadata?

**UPDATE:**
The [source code](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/5d4f51eb4efeeeea228610f57edd260c0eb021eb/harvesters/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/kernel/harvest/harvester/ogcwxs/Harvester.java#L333) of GeoNetwork Harvester tells that only layers with no children are harvested:

```
            //--- Select layers, featureTypes and Coverages
        // (for layers having no child named layer = not take group of layer into account)
        // and add the metadata
        XPath xp = XPath.newInstance("//Layer[count(./*[name(.)='Layer'])=0] | " +
            "//wms:Layer[count(./*[name(.)='Layer'])=0] | " +
            "//wmts:Layer[count(./*[local-name(.)='Layer'])=0] | " +
            "//wfs:FeatureType | " +
            "//wcs:CoverageOfferingBrief | " +
            "//sos:ObservationOffering | " +
            "//wps:ProcessSummary");
```

It is seems to me that I have to change XPath somehow to make it harvest all the layers. I am not a developer, so could anyone verify it is possible? :)

Comment: What happens if you configure the layer group to use mode "single" instead?

Comment: In "single" mode Layer Group appears in harvesting results. But I have to use "named tree" for purpose of another software.

Comment: Then you should perhaps publish the layer group as "opaque container" and each layer individually for the second time because opaque container removes the member layers from GetCapabilities. I do not know if it is possible but I wish you luck. Or create another virtual service for the other software.